# Django save or update model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using `Django 1.5.1` and I want to save or update model.

I read the django document and I met the `get_or_create` method which provides saving or updating. There is a usage like;

```
Model.objects.get_or_create(name='firstName',surname='lastName',defaults={'birthday': date(1990, 9, 21)})
```

`defaults` field is using only for getting. While it is setting phase, name and surname are only set. That is what I understand from the document.

So I want to do something different that setting name,surname and birthDay, but getting name and surname excluding birthdate. I could not see the way to do that in the document and another place.

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_or_create` provides a way of getting or creating. Not saving or updating. Its idea is: I want to get a model, and if it doesn't exist, I want to create it and get it.

In Django, you don't have to worry about getting the name or the surname or any attribute. You get an instance of the model which has all the attributes, I.e.

```
instance = Model.objects.get(name='firstName',surname='lastName')

print instance.birthday
print instance.name
print instance.surname
```

An overview of the idea could be: a `Model` is a data structure with a set of attributes, an instance is a particular instance of a model (uniquely identified by a `primary_key` (`pk`), a number) which has a specific set of attributes (e.g. `name="firstName"`).

`Model.objects.get` is used to go to the database and retrieve a specific instance with a specific attribute or set of attributes.

Comment: Do you mean, I am only getting an instance(created or existed) of the model to update it. So I can update it with extra fields

Comment: Yes. get is for getting the model. You can then change it (e.g. `instance.name = 'newName'`) and save it (`instance.save()`). This is how you normally "update" a particular instance. Notice that "update" in Django [has other meaning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once), that is why I added double quotes.

Comment: Setting extra fields on an instance is just like setting stuff on a normal object. However if you want it on the model then you have to do some fancy stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

Since Django 1.7 there's `update_or_create`:

```
obj, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(
    first_name='John',
    last_name='Lennon',
    defaults=updated_values
)
```

The parameters you give are the ones that will be used to find an existing object, the `defaults` are the parameters that will be updated on that existing or newly created object.

A tuple is returned, `obj` is the created or updated object and `created` is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create